# Update ElasticSearch mapping in production (Tire)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I would like to have a clear understanding on how to deal with the following scenario:

> I'm adding or removing an attribute from an activerecord model, so I want to update its mapping in ElasticSearch, in production.

From what I understood, I should...

#### 1- create a new index and import everything from mysql

Is this the right command? `rake environment tire:import CLASS='Bow' INDEX='new-bows'`
For this to create the right mapping, I should already have updated my mapping in the model, right?

#### 2- delete the old mapping and create an alias named `bows` for `new-bows`

I would do it like that, is it correct?

```
old_index_name = Bow.tire.index.name
Bow.tire.index.delete
alias = Tire::Alias.new
alias.name(old_index_name)
alias.index('new-bows')
alias.save
```

#### 3- restart app

---

**Am I missing something, or is there a simpler way to achieve what I want using Tire?**

**At what point should I delete the old index? Before creating the alias with the same name, or can I do it after?**

Comment: HI, i am using the import task on a model with 10Million rows, and dumping a lot of data into the index per record.

Any rough estimate how much time it should take?
My last check was 5% took around 8hrs. Is that normal?

Comment: Do you have to load associations? If so, don't forget to load them. I think there is an option for it, otherwise, I'd suggest to do the import yourself with `Tire.index(index_name).import batch`. Try to identify what part takes the longer maybe. The issue probably comes from the amount of data you have for each record. I have dealt in the past with millions of records, but it was much faster than 62.5k records/hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should keep the old index around until you're sure the new index is 100% what you want. You can flip the alias back if that would not be the case.

There's an integration test in Tire test suite for "flipping aliases".

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Not sure I understand how to test the new index. Should I point my app to the new index? Because I can't name the alias the same as the existing index so... (plus if you could give a quick definition of "indice", I'm confusing this term with "index"). Thanks :)

Comment: The point is, you can leave the old index as it is. No need for deleting it, unless you need the disk space/etc. The Ruby code you posted is fine and does what you need, though you need to create the new index first: `Bow.tire.create_elasticsearch_index`

Comment: Well, I can't actually do `alias.name(old_index_name); a.save` if I didn't delete the index first. Name conflict. So I need to point my app at an alias in the first place, so that I can flip it, and leave the index alone, I think.

Comment: > So I need to point my app at an alias in the first place -- Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 3):

To add a new column to an index:

```
index = Tire.index("articles")

index.mapping("article", :properties => { :pinterest_shares => {:type => 'integer', :index => 'not_analyzed', :include_in_all => false} })
```